# What is the proper way to read data from Firebase DB without authentication using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

[image]Let's say I want to implement a Fiverr site look-alike using Firebase (please see attached image).
So the DB should include a list of users, each has multiple attributes (like name, avatar image etc.).

**Without any authentication** - this site should show a list of these users, with some of their attributes (the ones that are "public", other attributes should be "private").
**Once a user has authenticated (logged in)** - he can see an "admin" section of the site - where he can read all attributes and update them.

**So my question is:**
What is the proper way to read data from Firebase DB, without authentication (to render the users list), but without setting a global ".read": true," DB rule?

Comment: Have you read the docs regarding the rules, and tried to implement some of the suggested patterns? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade

Comment: Yes I have.
What I'm looking for is another Firebase mechanism which will allow me to:
1. restrict access to each "user node" only to that authenticated user
2. but will still allow me to query data regarding these users and their properties

Is there such a mechanism? Can this be achieved using http cloud functions?

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a "proper" way to do this, but you should choose whatever is effective for your requirements.  An effective solution might be to have two locations, `/users_public` and `/users_private` with different rules based their intended visibility.  Obviously, `/users_public` should have global read access if for the data you want to be visible without authentication.

Comment: This is a possible solution.
but what I'm looking for is another Firebase mechanism which will allow me to:
1. restrict access to each "user node" only to that authenticated user
2. but will still allow me to query data regarding these users and their properties

Is there such a mechanism? Can this be achieved using http cloud functions?

Comment: You can read whatever data you want with the Admin SDK running in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to have security rules that do what you want and limit the editing ability to logged in users, but making the data publicly visible. Then on your website, check if the user is logged in, and then open a special page where they can edit their information if they would like to. You don't need to worry about random people going to this link and editing the information, because they have to be authenticated by your firebase rules. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a possible solution.
but what I'm looking for is another Firebase mechanism which will allow me to:
1. restrict access to each "user node" only to that authenticated user
2. but will still allow me to query data regarding these users and their properties

Is there such a mechanism? Can this be achieved using http cloud functions?